# Overrding get_queryset in the model file without having to create a new model manager in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model and I have used it at multiple places now and changing it all places is cumbersome. Could you please let me know how to do that? I already know the I can create a custom model manager but it's not feasible to change the model manager at all places.

```
class Slot(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SLOT_STATE, default=SLOT_STATE[0][0])
```

According to the docs-

```
# First, define the Manager subclass.
class DahlBookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(author='Roald Dahl')

# Then hook it into the Book model explicitly.
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    dahl_objects = DahlBookManager() # The Dahl-specific manager.
```

I want to retain the same default manager but I want to exclude all the NULL slot. P.S. slot can have null state.

Answer (score 1):

Following the docs, you could add a custom manager which returns only objects where `state is not NULL`:

```
class SlotNoNullStateManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(state__isnull=False)

class Slot(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = models.Manager()    # the default manager
    no_null_state_objects = SlotNoNullStateManager()
```

Now your model has 2 managers; and the default behaviour has not changed because it still uses the same default manager for `.objects`.

It is importante to NOT use `.filter()` in the `.get_queryset()` method of the default manger, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/managers/#don-t-filter-away-any-results-in-this-type-of-manager-subclass

---

If you really want to change the default behaviour, despite the warnings, the simply interchange the 2 managers:

```
class Slot(models.Model):
    ...

    # this has the be placed before the other manager, so that
    # it becomes the default manager
    objects = SlotNoNullStateManager()
    all_objects = models.Manager()
```

If you still want the rows that have NULL, then you use the manager `all_objects`.

Comment: that's the thing I want to change the default behaviour. so that when I use Slot.objects.all() it return me all the slot whose state is not null. That's what  i want to achieve.

Comment: @Comrade49 Are you sure? When the default manager filters out all the rows that have NULL, then `.objects.get()` won't be able to retrieve those rows, in the admin they won't appear, and some other places (see the link to the docs in the answer). It is possible, but not recommended.

Comment: @Comrade49 I edited my answer to include the option you want